# unable to navigate to particular screen on push notification click when app is killed(Flutter android)

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I m using firebase cloud messaging in my flutter application. I am unable to navigate to particular screen when I click on push notification.
It is working fine when app is in foreground and app is background but not in case when app is killed.

code:

```
class FcmHelper {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  void initializeFcm() {
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');


    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {      
        displayNotification(message);
        return;
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        displayNotification(message);
        return;
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        displayNotification(message);
        return;
      },

    );
 
  }


  Future displayNotification(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    // display notification
  }

  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    try {
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
      var tripDetails = HotelBookingDetails(
          );
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          GlobalVariable.navState.currentContext,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => tripDetails),
          ModalRoute.withName('/'));
    } catch (e, s) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: please paste relevant code here

Answer (score 1):

```
final noti = FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
```

You implement this in splash screen and go to your screen you want

Answer (score 0):

`onLaunch` callback will fire once `FirebaseMessaging` initialized,
maybe you can navigate with `navigatorKey` like so

```dart
      GlobalVariable.navState.currentState.push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (_) => YourPage(),
                        ),
                      );
```

if it does not help try to initialize `FirebaseMessaging` when context is available, maybe in MateriApp builder method

```
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, widget) {
     FcmHelper().initializeFcm();
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage message) {
    // add your condition if any
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/notifications", (route) => route.settings.name == "/notifications" ? false : true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to add under given line in the server-side body of the notification.
`"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"`, and the postman json is: `{ "to": "foP947GMRmuin1N********************", "priority": "high", "notification": { "title": "Sakib sent a offer", "body": "An electric bike used 2 years", "android_channel_id": "Messages", "count": 10, "notification_count": 12, "badge": 12, "color": "#eeeeee" }, "data": { "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", "type": "msj", "id": "1" } }`

And in your manifest just add following code:
`<intent-filter> <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> </intent-filter>`
then should be worked this method and it should be in the initstate method of your app :
`FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage message) { // add your navigation function or, any others });`